# UpdatedAt on mongodb official driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to insert/update the field updatedAt everytime that a document is modified on mongodb without defining it in every CRUD API?

Comment: mongoose has timestamp options. Read this http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Comment: I know, but I don't use mongoose, I use the mongodb official driver.